# Using non-optional object while swift consider it optional

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, optional-parameters

I have a coreData `NSManagedObject` as follows:

```
public class Records: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var uid: String
    @NSManaged public var datetime: Date
}
```

In addition, I have a helper to retrieve the record by UID:

```
func getRecordByUid(uid: String) -> Records!{
    do {
        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Records> = Records.createFetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uid = %@", uid)
        let result: [Records] = try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return result.first
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now, in my view controller I used a core-data object as non-optional (for adding new record or editing existing record purpose) as described below:

```
class AddRecordViewController: UIViewController {

    var container: NSPersistentContainer!
    var record: Records!
    var currentUid = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: PickerBasedTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // initialise core data
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

            if let error = error {
                print("Unsolved error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        if let existingRecord = Facade.share.model.getRecordByUid(uid: currentUid) {
            record = existingRecord
        } else {
            record = Records(context: self.container.viewContext)
        }

        // datePicker
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: record.datetime)

        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that it cause an error in `dateTextField.text =  ...` line, because it thinks the `record` is optional, however it isn't a case:

```
(lldb) po record
▿ Optional<Records>

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure `dateTextField` is not nil?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but Do not return an implicit unwrapped optional, return a regular optional `func getRecordByUid(uid: String) -> Records?` and Core Data entities are supposed to be named in singular form (`Record`)

Comment: `var record: Records!` definitely is an optional.  You've marked it for forced unwrapping, but that doesn't change the variable type.

Comment: @the4kman `dateTextField` is `IBOutlet`, yes

Comment: @vadian No I chose all of core-data objects plural intentionally

Comment: @PhillipMills I don't want it to be optional, but how?

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard In terms of language semantics when you insert a new object you are creating **one Record** not *one Records*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code would behave much better if you wrapped the fetch with the create into one method that always returns an object.

Something like

```
func getOrCreateRecord(uid: String) -> Records{
    var record: Records?
    do {
        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Records> = Records.createFetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uid = %@", uid)
        let result: [Records] = try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        record = result.first
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return record ?? Records(context: container.viewContext)
}
```

There still might be an issue with the text field but I still think it makes sense to create a wrapper method for this logic.

Comment: The last bit can be simplified to `return oldRecord ?? Records(context: container.viewContext)`

Comment: @Alexander, thanks. I assumed you meant record not oldRecord.

Comment: Ooops, yep, I did

Answer (score 1):

I think that `dateTextField` is probably nil, and the fatal error is related to it. Either that, or `Records(context: self.container.viewContext)` is a failable initializer that returns a nil object in some cases.

Comment: none of them unfortunately, the problem lies with Records which is optional in edit case (`if existingRecord`)  and shouldn't be optional